# IF statement in Excel to find 3 possible outcomes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have two columns that I'm using. Basically the gist of the outcome is the following. 
IF A2 is blank and B2 >0 then Status is New
Or A2>0 and B2 is blank then status is Churn
or A2>0 and B2>0 then status is retained.

Comment: You can have a 2nd `IF` statement in place of either the true or false return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I'm not quite sure what you meant about the statuses, but change as required. There is also a possibility of no match (anything less than or equal to zero) so you might need handling for that.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A2),B2>0),"New",IF(AND(A2>0,ISBLANK(B2)),"Churn",IF(AND(A2>0,B2>0),"Retained","NO CONDITION MATCHED!")))
```

Comment: Sorry, Status is the column name that I'm trying to populate with the statement. thanks for your help. I was getting stuck with the blank conditions.